# How do I mirror the data harddisk of my win 2008 server to a LAN drive or another local server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mirroring

As title, I have a server running win server 2008 but I want to create an HA environment (sort of)
by mirroring the data drive of the server to another local server/network drive. What is the best way to do this? Can I mount the network drive like a local drive so I can use the windows Drive Mirroring in Drive Management? Thanks

Comment: What kind of data?  What does this server DO?  It makes a big difference for what your HA options are.

Comment: just a lot of documents such as doc dwg xls etc.

Comment: just what is the best solution for me? Just in case the main server is down?

Comment: @saldtch More than one server.  Having more than one server is the only way to protect against one server being down.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve HA. What roles/features are installed on this server? Is it a physical server or a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Doing what you're asking would create a HU (high-unavailabilty) environment.  You basically can't mount the same drive on two different servers at the same time, because each server expects that it has complete control over the physical volumes it has mounted.  As soon as both servers start accessing the disk at the same time, serious problems are going to occur because of that - when one server wants one block on one part of the disk, and the other server wants a different block on a different part of the disk, what do you think is going to happen?  Each server is going to instruct the disk to retrieve the block *it* wants, and the disk is going to spin back and forth trying do to as instructed, and the only thing that's going to get returned are storage subsystem errors.

Mirroring actual data is much easier, and can be done any number of ways.  For Windows, DFS-R, `robocopy /MIR` and network drive maps all let you share file-level data between multiple machines, and NFS is probably the best option for presenting block-level data to multiple machines at once.  Which option is best for your environment completely depends on your environment, the details of which you haven't provided.

Figure out what, precisely, it is that you're looking to do, and research the options I listed.  (Google would probably be your best resource for the preliminary research you need to do yet.)  Once you settle on an option, or come up with questions more specific than "which one do I use?", you can move onto more involved research, which may even include asking questions online.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.  I have just read about robocopy but what is NFS? I read in a post robocopy doesn't support NFS? Sorry I didn't mention about the environment. We are a company of around 20 persons.  Now running a rather old dell server with win server 2008 with about 2TB of data,  mostly dwg pdf doc,  just standard office documents. We don't need a ultra fast server but would really like to improve the up down speed of the server.  (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) I don't want to make it complicated & I don't want to get another Windows server (I may rather setup a Linux server thou) that's why I looked into NAS units such as the synology 414. I want the existing Windows server as main server and mirror the data to the new backup server with whichever the most convenient protocol/software.I also want to do a backup of files that are changed on the server(incremental backup?) but where should I back this up to? Which server or maybe better to an external USB drive? Sorry for so many questions at once but I will keep doing my research. Thanks!